# Convert character 'A' to 'B' if I add 1

Tags: ruby

Suppose you have one character/string, "A".

What do you write to convert it to 'B' if add 1 to 'A'. If I add '2' it should be converted to 'C' and so on...

Comment: Please, provide more details on the problem.

Comment: -5? :) Was it that bad?

Comment: I guess that not enough information was given. It will be better if you provide more details. For instance: will you be working only with upper case? will you be adding to `Z`? if so, what behavior do you expect?

Comment: Aside from the rules, it's unclear what _"add 1 to 'A'"_ means. Do you want to write a function `convert('A', 1)` that returns `'B'` or do you want to alter the built-in `'A' + 1` so it returns `'B'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Furthering [Sergio's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44391747/5101493), you can isolate the letter-ordinals and use modulo.

```
class String
  def plus n
    case self
    when ('a'..'z')
      (((ord - 97 + n) % 26) + 97).chr            #ord means self.ord
    when ('A'..'Z')
      (((ord - 65 + n) % 26) + 65).chr
    else
      raise "single-letters only"
    end
  end
end

'a'.plus 2 #=> 'c'
'z'.plus 1 #=> 'a'
'A'.plus 0 #=> 'A'
'Z'.plus 9 #=> 'I'
'/'.plus 1 #=> test.rb:9:in `plus': single-letters only (RuntimeError)
```

Your question is unclear, but as alluded to in the comments by Stefan, you may want `'A' + 1 #=> 'B'` notation. Ruby does allow an overwrite of `String#+`. But don't do this, this is just to show you that you can:

```
class String
  def +(n)
   #code as above...
  end
end
```

then via syntactic sugar, you can do:

```
'a' + 2 #=> 'c'
'z' + 1 #=> 'a'
'A' + 0 #=> 'A'
'Z' + 9 #=> 'I'
'/' + 1 #=> test.rb:9:in `plus': single-letters only (RuntimeError)
```

Comment: Oh, you could use `case self` and `when 'a'..'z'` / `when 'A'..'Z'`

Comment: @Stefan I went for your `case self` idea. It looks much cleaner than what I had. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could roundtrip via `.ord`

```
'a'.ord # => 97
'a'.ord + 2 # => 99
('a'.ord + 2).chr # => "c"
('A'.ord + 5).chr # => "F"
```

Comment: Might be troublesome for `'z'` and `'Z'` etc.

Comment: @sagarpandya82: edge condition behaviour was not specified :)

Comment: Okay you got me. OP: if you're interested and want 'Z' to 'A' etc you may extend String and define something like:  `((((self.ord - 65) + n) % 26) + 65).chr`. Similarly for lowercase letters.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like?:

```
array = ('a'..'z').to_a
p array[array.index('a'.downcase) + 1].upcase
```

Comment: Or if you know are always capital letters `('A'..'Z')`, without down and upcase them.

Comment: You could benefit from `rotate` (i.e. `array[array.rotate(-1).index('a')]`) and avoid the `'z' + 1` problem.

Comment: That's nice and faster @Gerry!

Comment: @Gerry `array.rotate(1).first` would also work ;)

Comment: @Stefan I thought of it, but it will be locked to `'A'`, couldn't figure out another way to use any letter.

Comment: @Gerry maybe `array.rotate(array.index('b') + 1).first`. Slightly longer than yours, but the offset is positive and there's something like `'b' + 1` in the code.

Comment: @Stefan Ahh, yes, much better (i do hate the -1 offset).